# c# Winforms: Controlling what is displayed in a combo box but its binded to a list

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a list and i am binding my combo box to the list.

I have DisplayMember and ValueMember set to "NAME" and its working great, in the list its a collection of my classes and my class has other properties like Enabled (bool)..

So i would like for it to display the name from the name property and in brackets the word true or false depending on the property.

How can i control the displaymember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

1. Build a special list with the strings the way you want them.
2. Take a look at the Combobox.Format event. But I'm not sure how/if that works with Value/Display members.

Comment: @Marlin, for future reference you could answer your own Q here, showing how to use the FormatEventArgs